# server.transfer between applications

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, webforms, response.redirect, server.transfer

I have 3 applications under 1 solution with the following structure,

WebSoln,

- WebApp > Default.aspx
- SSOApp > SSO.aspx (contains only redirection to Default.aspx)
- TestApp > Test.aspx page

I have set the TestApp as the starting project and now I need the following flow. When I click a submit button in Test.aspx page it should go to SSOApp > SSO.aspx which in turn should redirect to Default.aspx  page under WebApp.

How can I transfer between application, I am trying to use Server.Transfer, I am not sure what URL should I be using. Can you please give me the URL that would help me transfer between the applications.

Answer (score 1):

`Server.Transfer` only works for the same application. You should use `Response.Redirect` method to redirect page in another application.

[Why we cant use Server.Transfer() to redirect on another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377765/why-we-cant-use-server-transfer-to-redirect-on-another-server)

[Will Server.Transfer work across AppDomains/Web Applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378940/will-server-transfer-work-across-appdomains-web-applications)

Lets say you have two application in the same iis.

Ex:  `Response.Redirect("http://server/otherapp/default.aspx");`

Comment: I am adding custom headers to http request, when I used Server.Transfer I used to retain these custom headers, but Response.Redirect is stripping this off. Can you please let me know how can I retain this with Response.Redirect.

Comment: Most of SO answers say that you can't keep custom headers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070430/response-redirect-with-headers . But this might work http://weblogs.asp.net/vikram/archive/2009/05/22/permanent-redirect-in-asp-net-4-0.aspx.